# How do I make it easy for users to upload images into a text area?

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

**I would like to make it easy for users to add images to text areas.**

I enabled the "Image" plugin for a TinyMCE 3.5.11 WYSIWYG profile in Drupal 7.

It looks like this:

[image]

**It is unclear, to the end user, how to upload an image. How can I make it easier?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively easy to install and enable the [IMCE module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce).

Then, I enabled it in my WYSIWYG Profile.

[image]

That gives you a little button next to the Image URL field.

[image]

And that allows the user to upload images.

FWIW, TinyMCE 4.3+ supports [image uploading](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/upload-images/) natively.